# Can you rebind your keys in the PC version?

Tags: friday-the-13th

So, Friday the 13th just launched on PC a few minutes ago, but I don't see any way to rebind the keys.

Does Friday the 13th support key rebinding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not support re-binding keys at the moment.

Comment: Apparently during the beta you could tweak an .ini file to alter the keybindings, but even that has since stopped working (changes aren't saved and the .ini is blank). Very odd decision by the devs not to add customisable keybindings!